# Dynamical pictures in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-evolution

I know that pictures in quantum mechanics are different ways to deal with a quantum problem. What keeps me confused is how to decide what picture I have to use?, i.e., for which quantum system do I use which picture?

Comment: They're equivalent, i.e. make the same physical predictions.

Comment: If they are completely equivalent, why is one picture not enough? @JasonFunderberker

Comment: One may be more convenient (than the others) in certain situations...